# Разметка в XAML, VisualBrush. vMix Titles

Tags: wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно передать содержимое текстового блока:

```
<TextBlock 
    Name="TypeIn"
    Text="RUS" />
```

значению ElementName:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=LANG}"/>
```

Желаемый результат:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=RUS}"/>
```

Comment: С помощью конвертера?

Comment: Программный видеомикшер vMix использует файлы XAML для создания динамически изменяемых графических элементов, таких как титры. С основами разметки в XAML разобрался, но написание конвертера, это уже програмирование... не силён, увы.
Рядом с файлом разметки XAML, лежат одноимённые файлы с расширением VB. Конвертер надо писать в нём, или он требует дальнейшей компиляции?
Спасибо.

Comment: Увы, с "Программный видеомикшер vMix" не встречался, но ответ добавил как это можно сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я завел следующий конвертер:

```
class TextToVisualConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var window = values[0] as Window;
        var elName = values[1] as string;
        return window.FindName(elName);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Он получает 2 значения - родительское окно и имя элемента, ищет этот элемент в окне и возвращает его.

Тестовая разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="400" Height="300"
        Name="w">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextToVisualConverter x:Key="conv"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="txt" Text="b1"/>

        <Button Name="b1" Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Button 1" BorderBrush="Green"/>

        <Button Name="b2" Grid.Row="2"
                Content="Button 2" Background="Yellow"/>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                            <Binding ElementName="w"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="txt" Path="Text"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Пример работы:

[image: Visual]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду пробовать, читать, разбираться.

Comment: @vMix_TTL если вам подошел ответ, отметьте его зеленой галочкой